# Unexpected identifier in Javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript module like:

```
$(() => {
    'use strict';

    const updateLabels = countryEl => {
        const selectedCountry = countryEl.value;
        var state = '';
        switch(selectedCountry){
            case 'JP':
                state = 'Prefecture';
                break;
            case 'CA':
                state = 'Province';
                break;
            case 'US'
                state = 'State';
                break;
        }
        <do other stuff>
    };
});
```

and when I call the `updateLabels` function, the browser console gives me the error:

```
address.js:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'state'
```

Maybe I'm losing my mind, but the `state` variable is clearly defined right before the switch statement. Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: You're missing a colon `:` on the previous line.

Comment: Any good IDE will show this error. Are you not using one?

Comment: `Unexpected identifier` doesn't mean the identifier wasn't defined, it means the token appeared in a place it shouldn't. JavaScript doesn't expect to find a random variable name up against a value in a case statement, ie `case 'US' state`.

Answer (score 1):

in JavaScript, each case in a switch statement should be followed by a colon, and your code was missing it after 'US'. Adding the colon should resolve the syntax error you were encountering.

```
$(() => {
    'use strict';

    const updateLabels = countryEl => {
        const selectedCountry = countryEl.value;
        var state = '';
        switch(selectedCountry){
            case 'JP':
                state = 'Prefecture';
                break;
            case 'CA':
                state = 'Province';
                break;
            case 'US': // Add a colon here
                state = 'State';
                break;
        }
        // <do other stuff>
    };
});
```